# how to check std::array is declared but not explicitly initialized

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

`std::array` has a built-in method `empty()` to check if the array is empty. As shown in the example copied from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/empty):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> numbers {3, 1, 4, 1};
    std::array<int, 0> no_numbers;
 
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "numbers.empty(): " << numbers.empty() << '\n';
    std::cout << "no_numbers.empty(): " << no_numbers.empty() << '\n';
}
```

Are there any ways to check if the array is declared, with some fixed size, but not explicitly initialized?

Say, something like this?

```cpp
std::array<int,4> a;
std::array<int,4> b;
a = {1,2,3,4}; //a holds some explicit values
//do not assign values to b
//how to tell the different state of a and b?
```

Comment: No. Reading an uninitialized variable is UB, and in practice will often result in getting garbage values, which can't be distinguished from contents of an initialized array.

Comment: For this to feature to exist, the state (initialized or uninitialized) of the array would need to be separately tracked. But `std::array` has no memory overhead compared to a C array, so it cannot support that. You can try `std::optional<std::array<int, 4>>` to add some sort of well defined "unspecified" state to your array.

Comment: Even with using regular arrays, you cannot tell if a regular array has been initialized or not.  A garbage `0` or `1` (or whatever your initial value would be) is just as possible as if the array were initialized with `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `std::array<T, N>::empty()` where N!=0 will always return `false`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/empty "Checks if the container has no elements, i.e. whether begin() == end()."

Similarly `std::array<T, 0>::empty()` will always return `true`, because `begin() == end()`.

Comment: Agree,  I spent half an hour to find what is wrong in my code.

` std::array<char,1024> achararr{0}; 
    if (achararr.begin() == achararr.end() ) std::cout << "array is empty\n";
    else std::cout << "array not empty\n" ;`

Answer (score 2):

The size of a `std::array` object (that is, the number of elements it has) *must* be a *compile-time* constant, and cannot be changed dynamically. Thus, the `empty()` and `size()` member functions would perhaps seem somewhat redundant<sup>†</sup> (but included for reasons of compatibility with generic, container-based algorithms provided by the STL).

If you need a container with a size that can be changed, then you should use `std::vector` instead of `std::array` (although this has more run-time overheads).

The following illustrates one of the differences:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> a;
    std::array<int, 4> b;
    a = { 1,2,3,4 }; //a holds some explicit values

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "a.empty(): " << a.empty() << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << "b.empty(): " << b.empty() << '\n'; // false

    // However ...
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;
    v1 = { 1,2,3,4 };
    std::cout << "v1.empty(): " << v1.empty() << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << "v2.empty(): " << v2.empty() << '\n'; // true

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>†</sup> But note, those members *are* useful for cases when an array is passed to a function, which otherwise would not be able to determine the size (or emptiness) of its given argument(s).

Comment: "*or, possibly, included for reasons of 'compatibility' with other container types provided by the STL*" - not for compatibility with *other containers*, but for compatibility with *standard algorithms* that operate on multiple container types in a generic manner. So there needs to be a consistent interface to those containers.  The algorithms don't care about the implementations of the containers, just the results of the interface.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the correction/clarification. I was actually a bit uncomfortable with my original wording (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're asking for:

> Are there any ways to check if the array is declared, with some fixed size, but not explicitly initialized?

If you have a variable of type `std::array`, then it has been constructed.
If it's been constructed, then the elements in the array have been constructed.
(that's done in the `array` constructor)

This variable `std::array<std::string, 5> sa;` contains 5 default-constructed strings.

So I don't know what you mean by "declared, but not explicitly initialized"

Comment: From the cppreference: *note that default initialization may result in indeterminate values for non-class T*. (Not that I'm saying you're *wrong* - just clarifying that default initialization will not always be the same as *explicit* initialization.)

Comment: I mean in ``std::array<int, 2> a={1,2}`` the a was given the values, but in ``std::array<int,2> b`` no explicit values were given to b. how to differentiate the state of a and b?

Comment: "How to differentiate the state of a and b?"   Um, compare them? that will tell you if they're different.  But I don't think that's what you're asking.